# IndexOutOfRangeException array index is out of range

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unityを使っています。初心者です。実行をすると、コンソールエラーで

> IndexOutOfRangeException array index is out of range

と

> The  referenced script on this  Behaviour is missing

と出ました。

エラーを調べてみましたが、よくわからなかったので　どなたか解決策を教えてください。

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player_NonPhysics2D:MonoBehaviour {
    //宣言
    // Inspectorで調整するためのプロパティ
    public float speed =15.0f;
    public Sprite[] run;
    public Sprite[] jump;

    //　内部で扱う変数

    float jumpVy;
    int animIndex;
    bool goalCheck;

    //メッセージに対応したコード
    //コンポーネントの実行開始

    void Start(){
        //初期化
        jumpVy = 0.0f;
        animIndex = 0;
        goalCheck = false;
    }

    //プレイヤーキャラのコリジョンに他のゲームオブジェクトのコリジョンが入った
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
        //ゴールチェック
        if(col.gameObject.name == "Stage_Gate"){
            //goal
            goalCheck = true;
            return;
        }
        //ゴール以外だったらステージを再読み込みしてリセット
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevelName);
    }

    //フレームの描き換え
    void Update() {
        if(goalCheck) { //ゴールチェック
            return;
            //ゴールだったら処理停止
        }

        //現在のプレイヤーキャラの高さを計算
        float height= transform.position.y + jumpVy;
        //接地チェック（高さが0なら接地している）
        if(height <= 0.0f) {
            //ジャンプ初期化
            height = 0.0f;
            jumpVy  = 0.0f;
            //ジャンプチェック
            if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){
                //ジャンプ処理
                jumpVy = +1.3f;
                //ジャンプスプライト画像に切り替え..
                GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = jump [0];
            } else {
                //走り処理
                animIndex++;
                if(animIndex <= run.Length){
                    animIndex = 0;
                }
                //走りスプライト画像に切り替え
                GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=run[animIndex];
            }
        } else {
            //ジャンプ後の降下中
            jumpVy -= 0.2f;
            //jumpVy -= 6.0f * Time.deltaTime; //正しい処理はこちら
        }

        //プレイヤーキャラの移動（座標設定）
        transform.position = new Vector3 (
            transform.position.x+speed*Time.deltaTime,height,0.0f);
        //下記のように相対移動で記述してもいい
        //transfor.Translate(speed*Time.deltaTime,jumpVy,0.0f);
        //transform.position += new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime,jumpVy,0.0f);
        //ただし次の書き方では雨後置かないので注意
        //transform.position.Set(
        // transform.position.x+speed*Time.deltatime,height,0,0f);
        //カメラの移動（座標の相対移動）
        GameObject goCam = GameObject.Find ("Main Camera");
        goCam.transform.Translate (speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f,0.0f);
    }
    // UnitGuIの表示
    void OnGUI(){
        //デバックテキスト
        GUI.TextField(new Rect(10,10,300,60),
                  "[Unity 2d Sample 3-1 A]\nマウスの左ボタンを押すと加速\nはなすとジャンプ");
        //リセットボタン
        if(GUI.Button (new Rect(10,80,100,20),"リセット")) {
            Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevelName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: エラーメッセージと一緒に行番号が出るので、そこを見れば一発ですよ。

Answer (score 4):

> IndexOutofRangeException array index is out of range

はこのあたり [Unity Error List](http://www.atsuhiro-me.net/unity/dev/unity-error-list) ※ページ中程

> The referenced script on this Behaviour is missing

はこのあたり [[Unity] Behaviour is missing! の原因オブジェクトの見つけ方](http://blog.be-style.jpn.com/article/91794043.html)
が参考になると思います。

最初は大変だと思いますが、どんな開発でもエラー調査は必須スキルですので、
がんばってください（IDEの見方、使い方を学ぶのも有効だと思います）。

----- 追記 -----

```
//走り処理
animIndex++;
if(animIndex <= run.Length){
    animIndex = 0;
}
//走りスプライト画像に切り替え
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=run[animIndex];
```

手元で確認できないので詳細は分かりませんが、これだと`animIndex`が`run`の要素数を超えることは普通にありえますね。

この実装だとこんなイメージです。

```
animeIndex = 6;
// run.Length = 5
run = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 

// 6は５より大きいので分岐には入らない
if (6 <= 5) {
    animIndex = 0;
}
// runのindexは最大4なので「IndexOutofRangeException」
var sprite = run[6];
```

Comment: サイト拝見しましたが、＞＞配列(Array)で、宣言した個数よりも大きな番地を指定している。　と書いてあるのですが、コードを確認したのですが、それらしいところが見つかりませんでした。。。
　
else{
    //走り処理
    animIndex ++;
    if(animIndex <= run.Length){
     animIndex = 0;
    }
    //走りスプライト画像に切り替え
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=run[animIndex];　←エラーが出た場所
   }

Comment: もう一度回答いただけないでしょうか。。

Comment: @user8269 回答を追記しました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。　　animIndex、runのindexはなぜその数字にになるのでしょうか？　　　indexの「」の中に入る数字が最大値を超えているのでエラーがでてるのはわかりました。

Comment: @user8269 数字に意味はありません。ここで言いたいのは現在の実装だと配列の範囲を超える値が入ってくる可能性があるため修正が必要ではないかということです。これ以上は言及しませんので、あとは自分で頑張ってみてください。

Answer (score 1):

配列の添字が0より小さいか、もしくは配列の要素数以上であると発生する例外です。